# How to force an integer into two digits exactly in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

The problem is from my trying to convert number into a time format. I'd like to put time like "8:5" into "08:05". Any elegant JavaScript code?

Comment: Try momentjs. But even then you have to write your own js i believe.

Answer (score 2):

Use `split`, `map`, `slice` and `join`

```
"8:5".split(":").map((s)=>("0"+s).slice(-2)).join(":"); //prints 08:05
```

You can invoke this at the `blur/change` event of your input box.